# Is there a way to paint every second pixel in photoshop? (For dithering)

Tags: pixel, photoshop, dithering

I'm asking this question with regards to drawing pixel art. If I want to draw a line for example, I can just click on one pixel with my pencil tool, hold shift and click where I want the line to end. I was wondering if there was some way to do the same, but only paint every other pixel so I don't have to paint every other pixel individually whenever I want to achieve the dithering effect. This is especially annoying when I'm doing a long line.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: Is this a coding question? If yes please expand on what you've tried. If not, maybe graphic design stack exchabge is a better place for it.

Comment: There is. But the bad robots here don't like anyone talking about anything but code. Clue: Define Pattern & Layer Mask on a 2x2 pixel dither pattern

Answer (score -1):

Start with a new layer,then Draw a line you want
and click "ctr + J", You can create new copy of the same line.